# How can I break out of a .forEach loop in javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this code:

```
    self.tests.forEach((test: ITestRow) => {
        test.current = false;
        if (test.adminTestId == adminTestId &&
            (userTestId == 0 || test.userTestId == userTestId) &&
            (sequence == 0 || test.sequence == sequence)) {
            self.test = test;
            test.current = true;
            test.testId = testId;
            test.userTestId = userTestId;
        }
    });
```

I am not sure why but there are some cases where it sets more than one or the objects in the tests array to have current = true.  I keep seeing this but I am having a hard time duplicating it.

Would appreciate any advice on if I am doing something wrong with the logic. Also is there a way that I can break out of the .forEach as there will be at most only one row that should be set to true at one time.

Comment: Have you tried using "break;"?

Comment: what is `test: ITestRow`?

Comment: Beat me to it @Filkolev